# Using or in grep command

Tags: regex, terminal, grep, solaris

I tried the following commands

```
cat filename.txt | grep "<Line: (429|6854)>"
cat filename.txt | grep "<Line: \(429\|6854\)>"
```

to show the lines containing <Line: 429> or <Line: 6854> but I'm not getting any output.

Comment: This question probably belongs on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You need a pipe `|` between the filename and grep

Comment: @tom That is not a good answer.  `grep` can read files, so no `|` pipe and no `cat` is needed.

Comment: @Jotne, tom was referring to the commands as written in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `grep -E` or `egrep`:

```
grep -E '<Line: (429|6854)>' filename.text
```

Comment: not enough: the pipe between cat and grep is missing too. And while I'm there: I prefer egrep and fgrep over grep with options

Comment: I'm guessing that was just a typo when copying to SO, since he said he's not getting any output.